# In python, how to call a function with an argument on a click event

Tags: python, gmpy

I created the code below, but when I click on the `click me` button I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'mpfr' object is not callable
```

Would someone know what is wrong with the code?

```
import gmpy2 as g
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)

max_precision = g.get_max_precision()
pi = g.const_pi()
g.set_context(g.context())

def set_bits_precision(decimal_precision):
    bits_precision = int(decimal_precision/g.log(2))
    if (bits_precision > max_precision): bits_precision = max_precision
    ctx = g.get_context()
    ctx.precision = bits_precision
    return

def square_root(number):
    return g.sqrt(number)

def circle_perimeter(radius):
    return 2*pi*radius 

def on_button_clicked(x):
    return square_root(x)

set_bits_precision(10)
print(pi)
button.on_click(on_button_clicked(2))
```

Comment: Usually 'object is not callable' usually means you have used a left-paren after an identifier. In your case perhaps you have  'mpfr   ('  when  probably you meant something like 'mpfr, (' . That is, you are missing something (like a punctuation) after the mpfr.

Comment: `button.on_click` takes a callable as its argument. `on_button_clicked(2)` does not evaluate to a callable, it evaluates to a number (of type `mpfr`)

Comment: @ArtSwri No. That is not the issue at all. Did you even look at their code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`button.on_click` must be given a callback function. You pass the *result* of `on_button_clicked` evaluated with parameter 2 (so, literally the square root of 2) instead of passing in a function. You can use partial function evaluation to do what you want, by replacing your last line of code with:

```
import functools
button.on_click(functools.partial(on_button_clicked, 2))
```

Comment: Interesting! But I'm getting the following error: "TypeError: on_button_clicked() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @OlivierdeBroqueville on_click passes 1 argument to the callback. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Thank you jbch. It's working fine now. I had to do the following changes to the on_button_clicked function >> def on_button_clicked(x, b):

Comment: @OlivierdeBroqueville Yeah that will work, sorry I got busy elsewhere, probably wont have time to edit my answer for a while. Feel free to edit it or add your own answer with the correct code.